# Need help resetting static global variables in C

Tags: c, reference, struct

I'm going to be straight here, I'm an absolute novice when it comes to C and I'm a bit out of my depth here and need a little help. I am tweaking some source code and need to reset some static globals so that they can be used again. I've tried all sorts of things which just end in bad access errors - any help would be appreciated.

```
static struct option long_options[2 * countof (option_data) + 1];
static char short_options[128];
static unsigned char optmap[96];
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
memset(&long_options[0], 0, 2 * countof (option_data) + 1);
memset(&short_options[0], 0, sizeof(short_options));
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the "all sorts of things" that you've tried?

Comment: memset(&long_options[0], 0, 2 * countof (option_data) + 1);
memset(&short_options[0], 0, sizeof(short_options));

Comment: Your first `memset` is missing a `sizeof(struct option)`. So it's not zeroing the entire region. But that shouldn't segfault. (at least not during the memset)

Comment: I think it segfaults during the second run because the struct is not configured the way it's expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
memset(long_options, 0, sizeof(long_options));
memset(short_options, 0, sizeof(short_options));
memset(optmap, 0, sizeof(optmap));
```

Comment: won't that just empty them? I need them to be initialised just as they were when the program first loaded.

Comment: @BigBadOwl, if you have defined them as static (and not placed them in an uninitialized area of memory), then they will be initialized to zero.  This happens before main().  Both of the examples above will zero out the contents of the static variables.  The {0} syntax is shorthand.  This will zero out the entire array.  sizeof operates differently depending if you pass it a data type or an array.

Comment: @JoshPetitt: `{0}` is a valid initializer, but not a valid expression; it can't appear on the RHS of an assignment.

Comment: @KeithThompson I got confused because sometimes I do things like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494341/c-initializer-with-cast-is-this-dangerous