# C initializer with cast, is this dangerous?

Tags: c

Consider the following:

```
struct Foo 
{
  char c;
  int i;
};


void Bar(void)
{
  struct Foo f = {0}; // use zero initializer

  // do some stuff

  f = (struct Foo) {'h', 1}; // copy different data into f, is this dangerous?
}
```

Would the cast above be considered dangerous?  Is this good style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a matter of style; that code won't compile without the `(struct Foo)`.  It's not a cast, it's part of the syntax for a C99 feature known as a *compound literal*.

Comment: got it, I didn't know the name of the feature.  Thanks! (will accept shortly)